# Iterating over timestamp (date and hour)

Tags: scala, loops, timestamp

I have some function that gets as an input specific starting-timestamp and end-timestamp (e.g. *"2018-01-01 16:00:00"* and *"2018-01-01 17:00:00"*) (in the beginning of the code i `import java.sql.Timestamp`)

I want to iterate this function over time (e.g. - between 2018-01-01 until 2018-01-10, over each hour separately).
The furthest I got so far was iterating over the date, using `import java.time.{LocalDate, Period}`
but when I tried to change my code to `import java.time.{LocalDateTime, Period}`, it didn't work:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit 
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY 
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, Period} 

val start = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 1,6,20) 
val end = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 11,6,30) 
val dates: IndexedSeq[LocalDateTime] = 
  (0L to (end.toEpochSecond() - start.toEpochSecond())).map(hours => 
    start.plusHours(hours)
  )
dates.foreach(println)
```

Would highly appreciate your help!

Comment: I think the toEpochSecond() method takes a parameter java.time.ZoneOffset

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of both scala streams and localdatetime API to make things easier than what you tried, which is let's say, a bit too low level ^^ !

```
val allDatesBeforeEnd = Stream.iterate(start)(_.plusHours(1)).takeWhile(_.isBefore(end)).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, Period}

val start = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 1,6,20) 
val end = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 1, 11,6,30) 

val periodInHours = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()).getDays*24       
val dates: IndexedSeq[LocalDateTime] = (0L to periodInHours).map(start.plusHours(_))
dates.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first get the number of hours between the two datetimes and then loop over the range formed by this number of hours to create the range of datetimes:

```
val allDatesBeforeEnd =
  (0L until ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start, end)).map(start.plusHours(_))
```

Although I do prefer reading [C4stor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595709/9297144) this solution might be slightly better in terms of performance as it doesn't perform the `takeWhile` `isBefore` check for each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it prints all the hours between yesterday and today, just adapt it you use case :

```
  val yesterday =  LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1)
  val today =  LocalDateTime.now()

  Stream.iterate(yesterday){
    h => h.plusHours(1)
  }.takeWhile(_.isBefore(today)).foreach(println(_))
```